How to Swap Monitor Outputs
I'm trying to setup a virtual Monitor for different purposes, e.g. screen sharing. And I think I already succeeded in this, so I now have two different outputs shown, when using the xrandr command:
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3843 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.03
... zap ...
HDMI-1 disconnected 1920x1080+1923+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     60.03*

eDP-1 is my Laptop display and HDMI-1 is the not existing 'virtual' display. Now my question is simple. How can I swap the contents of these two outputs, such that I am able to use the virtual display? By swap I mean, that I want to transfer the output of HDMI-1 to eDP-1. After I used the virtual display, of course, I want to be able to revert the swap, so the original contents should not be lost.
To clarify, since "swapping displays" is a bit ambigous: There are already some answers on how to swap between dual and single monitor settings or how to swap the position of screens in a dual monitor setting. However I coulnd't derive a solution for my problem from these settings. My problem rather compares to a dual monitor setting where I want to swap what is seen on both monitors.
Edit: Another way to accomplish what I want to do would be to setup two virtual monitors on the same screen and switch between them, or resize them, as asked in this question.
